# Firebase: avoiding READs when updating data

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am currently setting up my 1st Firebase store and wondering how to best avoid unnecessary read/write costs (as well as how to create a nested structure...). Quite helpful was [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60535986/13648205).

However, if I listen to changes (caused by other persons) of a document, I assume I also get any change of myself again in return. So when using the logic of the todo example for bloc, I update a document. My listener recognizes this and fires an event to re-read the data from the repository.

```dart
@override
  Stream<TodosState> mapEventToState(TodosEvent event) async* {
    if (event is LoadTodos) {
      yield* _mapLoadTodosToState();
    } else if (event is TodosUpdated) {
      yield* _mapTodosUpdateToState(event);
    } else if (event is UpdateTodo) {
      yield* _mapUpdateTodoToState(event);
    }

  Stream<TodosState> _mapLoadTodosToState() async* {
    _todosSubscription?.cancel();
    _todosSubscription = _todosRepository.todos().listen(
          (todos) => add(TodosUpdated(todos)),
        );
  }

  Stream<TodosState> _mapTodosUpdateToState(TodosUpdated event) async* {
    yield TodosLoaded(event.todos);
  }

  Stream<TodosState> _mapUpdateTodoToState(UpdateTodo event) async* {
    _todosRepository.updateTodo(event.updatedTodo);
  }
```

Since I assume there may be multiple near time changes to a document by the same user in my app, is setting the source option to offline cache for 1min with each write access a proper option or are there better options?

And in case there isn't, can I somehow ensure that the data is sent when the user leaves the app (eg. when bringing another app upfront)?

And is there any overview how to use Firestone with Flutter? Unfortunately the coding examples in [Google's documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data?hl=en#python_5) are for any language but Dart/Flutter. How would I, for example, set the source option with Flutter (haven't searched for it yet)?

Comment: You should not optimize for reads in that way. It is not worth the cost - I assume you are working on a hobby project if you are worrying about this, however, you should still just be fine using realtime listeners where you need them, even when you are writing data to those locations.

Comment: Yes, it is currently a hobby POC, but could potentially turn out in a little commercial app. But of course I could start as you suggest and if it should ever scale change that logic, then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really can't have it both ways, you would either need to give up realtime or assume that this could generate more costs and as mentioned by @creativecreatorormaybenot you should still be using Listeners to deal with realtime updates.

The comments made in the accepted answer you shared are valid points to take better advantage of listeners with the use of cache and specially pagination, as you are very likely not required to have all of your documents in memory all the time.

Also, listeners are rather unexpensive for small projects, as you appears to be, and you have a free tier of 50.000 reads a day for Firestore, which will include read that come from listeners.